# Chaptermark not changing

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

Similar questions have been asked, but after reading them i still think the code below should lead to the beginning of a chapter being displayed as

1 Some Chapter

rather than

Chapter 1
Some Chapter

But when compiling i just get the latter, default book chapter head. I must be missing something.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{something}
\end{document}
```

Comment: chaptermark is used for the headings and footings. You want to change the style of the chapter page. There are various related questions, most of which will lead you to the titlesec package

Comment: Welcome! `marks` don't affect how the title of the chapter is displayed. They are typically used in setting up headers and footers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chapter` title is set with `\@makechapterhead`, being called within `\@chapter`, which is itself is used by `\chapter`.

The normal definition of `\@makechapterhead` is (see `book.cls`)

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

The lines             `\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter`
display **Chapter 1** and then eject a linebreak. If this is not wanted, the `\@chapapp` can be removed and \thechapter kept, then remove `\par\nobreak` etc. as well, otherwise, this would lead to a linebreak and vertical spacing for the title, with is hold in `#1`.

A similar code is used by starred `\chapter*` command, the relevant macro is named `\@makeschapterhead`, but I omitted this here.

The `\vspace*{50\p@}` should be updated to appropiate values, but this is a matter of taste, grossly. 
    \documentclass{book}

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \thechapter~\space
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{something}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

A 'quicker' solution is to use `\xpatchcmd` from the `xpatch` package.

[image]

The same effect, with `\xpatchcmd`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{% Old code
\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
}{% New code
  \huge\bfseries \thechapter~\space
}{\typeout{Patch success!}}{\typeout{Patching failed :-(}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{something}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had a similar block in an exmple document, but refused to just copy-paste, as i want to learn proper latex usage(Plus it's relly difficult copy-pasting exactly the right stuff). Your explanation was very helpful!

Comment: @Scipio: Normally, it's better to use `\xpatchcmd`. I will add another solution, which does not require copying the 'right' stuff completely

Answer (score 2):

Only if you can switch to an other class:

With class **`memoir`** you could use the command `\chapterstyle{section}` to get the desired result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{section}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the class **`scrbook`** knows an option `chapterprefixline=false`

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was actually aware, memoir could do this, but i spent a bunch of time arranging some special pages(title page, some officially required stuff which needs to look exactly like the broken Master is was provided...) using fancyhdr, which does not go together with memoir, so unfortunately i had to drop memoir as a possible solution, though it looks like a really usefull document class.